# How do I prevent MySQL from filling up the disc with binary log files

Tags: mysql

I have the following settings in my /etc/my.cnf

```
log-bin                 = /var/lib/mysql_bin_logs/mysql-bin.log
expire_logs_days        = 3
max_binlog_size         = 100M
relay-log               = /var/lib/mysql/slave-relay.log
relay-log-index         = /var/lib/mysql/slave-relay-log.index
log-slave-updates
```

and I can see that the `/var/lib/mysql_bin_logs/` folder remains at a constant size.  However the disc is filling up and I think it is to do with the file descriptor's for these binary log file not being closed properly.  When I restart MySQL, disk usage drops by several Gigabytes, suggesting that act of restarting is freeing up the space.

How do I prevent the disk being filled up this way other than restarting MySQL on a cronjob?

Comment: Does a mysqladmin flush-logs free that space?

Answer (score 1):

First I'd try `lsof -u mysql` while it's running to see what files MySQL has open.  You may also find it more helpful to do `lsof -u mysql | grep deleted` to see files that MySQL still has open but are deleted.  If it turns out to be the log files hanging around you could try issuing a `FLUSH LOGS` inside MySQL as a workaround and see if it closes them.